# command line prettify BSON

Tags: shell, bson, prettify

been working with mongo recently, which means a ton of very large nested hashes in (basically) json format. Currently I am piping json through `python -mjson.tool` in emacs, which works great for json, but bson also includes ObjectId("key"), and ISODate("date") (for example, `{"_id": ObjectId("4ec319b0e35c1f1063000015"), "date": ISODate("2011-11-16T00:00:00Z")}` which are not valid json, and causes the python lib to puke.

Does anyone know of a more lenient prettifier? Or some other way to accomplish the job for BSON. I don't even mind if the solution drops the wrapping functions, it is more to be able to visualize a deeply nested json datastructure easier

Comment: have you found a solution for your problem ?

Comment: @ascobol: not really. my issue was with mongo output, but I discovered chaining .pretty() at the end of my results would prettify them in the shell. Would definately still like an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH BSON parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318086/bash-bson-parser)