# BASH BSON parser

Tags: bash, parsing, mongodb, bson

We need to do some queries of a Mongo DB from BASH shell scripts.  Using eval and Mongo's printjson() gives me text output, but it needs to be parsed.  Using other scripting languages (Python, Ruby, Erlang, etc) is not an option.

I looked at JSON.sh ( a BASH script lib JSON parser: https://github.com/rcrowley/json.sh ) and it appears to be close to a solution other than the issue that it does not recognize BSON-but-not-JSON data types.  Before I try to mod it to recognize BSON data types, is anyone aware of an existing solution?

Thanks.

10/11   Below Stennie notes that I have received an answer in the MongoDB User group, and provides a URL.  The answer is very nice and complete, and begins, "MongoDB actually uses what we call Mongo Extended JSON which differs a bit from the vanilla JSON standard..." so I will have to modify the parser.  Thanks to all.

Comment: What are the limitations on calling "other interpreters" or helper programs?  JSON.sh uses `sed` for parsing; wouldn't interpreters such as AWK or Perl be fair game if installed by default in your server environment (with a solution limited to using pre-installed core modules only)?

Comment: Stennie:  Anything available in vanilla RedHat/SUSE is fair game.  We just can't do an install of a contemporary scripting language.  (I don't see Perl)  I would be willing to pitch a Mongo BASH driver if anyone is going there...   CVSDave

Comment: What exactly is the source of limitation? You can't install anything big or can't install at all? Can't you at least have executable files in your home? You might try something small like Lua then.

Comment: Oleg:  customers are customers; we can install only our software.  I guess there are a variety of concerns, some legitimate, some foolish, but those are the limitations under which I must work.  I have bash, Mongo. and the *nix utilities.

Comment: This question is also being discussed in the [mongodb-user group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/bf3375f921bcac3e).

Answer (score 2):

Do you perhaps want to use `tojson()` rather than `printjson()` and loop through the result of tojson() to parse the fields?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference.  The problem seems to be that BSON allows a variety of right-hand tokens, like ObjectId("123456789") that JSON (and so the JSON parsers) do not allow, and so interpret as corrupted format.